# Aggregation using D3JS collection(Nests) API?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am going to create bubble chart in D3JS library using Angular 7 framework. So, I am in need of nested collection of dataset.

> My Code

```
`this.month_keys = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'];
this.nested_data = d3.nest<any, Array<Object>>()
.key(function (d) { return d['username']; })
.rollup(function (leaves) {
 return [{
   'January': leaves[0]['January'],
   'February': leaves[0]['February'],
   'March': leaves[0]['March'],
   'April': leaves[0]['April']
 }];
})
.entries(data);`
```

> My Data set

`[{
April: "6000"
February: "5000"
January: "2500"
March: "7000"
id: "01"
username: "AAAA"
}, and etc.,]`

> Expected Result

`[
      'key': 'AAAA'
       'values': [
       {
         'name': 'January',
         'salary': 85000
       },
       {
        'name': 'February',
        'salary': 80000
      }
      {
        'name': 'March',
        'salary': 65000
      }
       ] 
    ]`

Comment: why do you need `d3.nest` for this, just a simple forEach over your data is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `d3.nest` here as you can just map your data to the desired format (although I've posted a solution with d3.nest() within the snippet). Here's how:

```
var mapped_data = data.map(function (d) {
  return {
    key: d['username'],
    values: month_keys.map(function (month) {
      return {
        name: month, salary: d[month]
      }
    })
  }
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var data = [{
 April: "6000",
 February: "5000",
 January: "2500",
 March: "7000",
 id: "01",
 username: "AAAA"
}];

var month_keys = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'];

var mapped_data = data.map(function (d) {
 return {
   key: d['username'],
    values: month_keys.map(function (month) {
     return {
       name: month, salary: d[month]
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(mapped_data);

console.log("Using d3.nest");
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function (d) { return d.username; }) // key is username
  .rollup(function (d) {
    // same as the mapping logic but here d would be an array of length 1 (checkout http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html)
    return month_keys.map(function (month) {
     return {
       name: month, salary: d[0][month]
      }
    });
  }).entries(data);
  
console.log(nested_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to achieve this solution in d3js using nest collection?

Comment: Edited the post with a solution using `d3.nest` although a simple mapping in this case would be just fine.

Comment: How to resolve this problem without having of  `month_keys` array?

Comment: I'm sorry you can't come up with a new requirement every day within the same post. If you're clear what you want to achieve, post it with a detailed explanation on what exactly you tried in achieving that and the SO community will help you resolve the issues (if any). And I'd suggest you read [how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post a question. Thanks.